# Existence of the Square in "Squaring the Circle" Problem

Tags: geometry, book-recommendation, geometric-construction

I understand that a square with area $\pi$ cannot be constructed using straightedge and compass. But such a square surely exists (and can be constructed through other means), right? If I'm right, I'm confused by the Wikipedia article (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squaring_the_circle)'s statement that seems to say squaring the circle is equivalent to asking whether the square with area $\pi$ exists. Can someone help me resolve this contradiction?

And if someone can point me to a good book covering these matters, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's equivalent to asking whether the square with area $\pi$ exists **in** the set of all squares that can be constructed using a straightedge and compass.

Comment: I agree with that, but the statement I'm having trouble with is this: "More abstractly and more precisely, it may be taken to ask whether specified axioms of Euclidean geometry concerning the existence of lines and circles entail the existence of such a square."

Comment: @FreshAir But that's just a more complicated way of writing what I wrote...

Comment: 5xum, I'm glad we're on the same page. So then you agree that the square with area $\pi$ exists? That statement on ""existence of such a square" seems to say it doesn't...

Comment: @5xum: The quote suggests that a square exists if and only if it can be demonstrated according to the specified axioms, and that those axioms are the ones corresponding to straight edge and compass construction.

Comment: @Henry I'm terribly sorry, I meant to ping the OP and got confused with the user-names... ^^'

Comment: @FreshAir Re-read the sentence with my emphasis: "ask **whether** specified **axioms** of Euclidean geometry concerning the existence of lines and circles **entail** the **existence** of such a square" (here *entail* has the same meaning of *imply*). The point is not the existence of such a square *in every possible framework* (one could say that everything exists within the scope of the right axioms), but its existence *in the framework of Euclidean geometry*, which is **the same** (at least as far as this problem is concerned) as the framework of straightedge-and-compass constructions.

Comment: @FreshAir I agree with you that such a square exists, but I don't agree that the statement is wrong. The statement says that it does not exist *in the particular space* constructed using Euclid's axioms.